# How to append single div for the same JSON values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have a JSON file that contains the sub divs and those sub divs have the device value of which device they belong to. So I need to create a loop using those device values. How can I achieve that?

Example: There is device 1 and device 2, I must create a single div for each, using their sub events values.

```html
<div id="device-1">
  <div id="event-1"></div>
  <div id="event-2"></div>
</div>
<div id="device-2">
  <div id="event-3"></div>
  <div id="event-4"></div>
</div>
```

```js
[{
  "event-1": { "device": "1" },
  "event-2": { "device": "1" },
  "event-3": { "device": "2" },
  "event-4": { "device": "2" }
}]
```

Comment: Please correct my English if it is complex, it was hard to explain my problem

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an HTML example of the <div> structure you want?

Comment: Thanks, I edited it, can you guys please check it again

Comment: What are those `...` parts? Are they significant at all?

Comment: They mean that there are more values but unnecessary to add into the question - I removed them

Comment: So your JSON array therefore contains only one unique element (with four `event-x` objects inside this one)... so why do use an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of the object, and find the correct device div element for each event. If one doesn't exist yet, you can add it to the DOM.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    'event-1': {
      device: '1',
    },
    'event-2': {
      device: '1',
    },
    'event-3': {
      device: '2',
    },
    'event-4': {
      device: '2',
    },
  },
];

const events = arr[0];

for (const eventName of Object.keys(events)) {
  const event = events[eventName];
  const deviceID = `device-${event.device}`;
  let deviceDiv = document.querySelector('#' + deviceID);

  if (!deviceDiv) {
    deviceDiv = document.createElement('div');
    deviceDiv.id = deviceID;
    document.body.appendChild(deviceDiv);
  }

  const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
  eventDiv.id = eventName;
  deviceDiv.appendChild(eventDiv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one worked for my case

Comment: Note that this solution is not exactly the most performant - you're calling document.querySelector for each event in your object - if the object is very large, you should try an approach like the one proposed by @MisterJojo where the device divs are stored in an array, instead of being queried from the DOM every iteration.

Comment: Alright, I will. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that...

```js
const data =
  [ { "event-1": { "device": "1", otherA : "a", otherB : "b" /* , otherX : "x" */ }
    , "event-2": { "device": "1", otherA : "a", otherB : "b" /* , otherX : "x" */ }
    , "event-3": { "device": "2", otherA : "a", otherB : "b" /* , otherX : "x" */ }
    , "event-4": { "device": "2", otherA : "a", otherB : "b" /* , otherX : "x" */ }
  } ]

Object.entries(data[0]).reduce((acc,[event_id,{device, ...others }])=>
  {
  if (!acc[device])
    { 
    acc[device] = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    acc[device].id = `device-${device}`
    }
  let event_el = acc[device].appendChild(document.createElement('div')) 
  event_el.id =  event_id  
  return acc
  },{})
```

```css
div { width:20em; height: 1em;}
body > div       { background: blue; padding: 1em;}
body > div > div { background: green; }
```

result =

```html
<div id="device-1">
  <div id="event-1"></div>
  <div id="event-2"></div>
</div>
<div id="device-2">
  <div id="event-3"></div>
  <div id="event-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reformat your object to be a list of devices that have arrays of sub events first, then output that to HTML

```js
let json = [{
  "event-1": {
    "device": "1"
  },
  "event-2": {
    "device": "1"
  },
  "event-3": {
    "device": "2"
  },
  "event-4": {
    "device": "2"
  }
}]

let devices = Object.keys(json[0]).reduce((b, a) => {
  let de = json[0][a].device
  b[de] = b[de] || [];
  b[de].push(a);
  return b;
}, {})

//console.log(devices)

let content = '';
for (k in devices) {
  content += `<div class='device'> <h2>Device ${k}</h2>${devices[k].join('<br />')}</div>`
}
document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```